# Send HTML mail with NAIL?

Tags: linux, email, command-line, centos, html-email

I'm on a CENTOS machine, trying to send an HTML mail using NAIL.

I've searched the web high and low, but all I can find is people saying to use the option '-s "Content-type: text/html;"', this however - does not work.

A more correct question perhaps would be; how do I add header lines to mails sent by NAIL?

B.R. / F

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer is nail cannot handle this.

Someone asks that on the mailx devel mailing list, and the answer is:

> mailx is an e-mail client, not an e-mail transfer agent.  You need to
>   call Postfix directly.

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=201101250955.36795.giecrilj%40stegny.2a.pl&forum_name=nail-devel

You can set some headers using the -t function, and you'll see an error message of what headers are ignored.

```
nail -t < email_file
```